# difference between 3NF and EKNF

Tags: database

Hi I am working on databases normalization and I am not able to see the difference between a database in 3NF form and one in EKNF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_Key_Normal_Form). Does anyone have an example of a database in 3NF but nor in EKNF ?
Thanks for your time

Comment: Never heard of EKNF, know of BCNF, is that what you meant?

Comment: no I am speaking of EKNF : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_Key_Normal_Form

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, I am writing this answer. If you have any query let me know. We can discuss.
I assume you know transitivity. I am repeating the same thing, If there is a relation R(A,B,C) and FD's are (A->B, B->C) then we call it transitive dependency and relation is not in 3NF. If FD's are like (AB->C, C->A).

- R(A,B,C)
- FD(AB->C, C->A)
- key = AB

3NF :  If FD's are like F(AB->C, C->A) then it is in 3NF.

EKNF : A relation R is in EKNF if for every elementary FD in F X->Y.

- Either X is a key or
- Y is **elementary prime attribute***.

  Here C->A. C is not a key or A is not a elementary prime attribute. 
  So, it is not in EKNF.
- **Elementary FD :** A non-trivial FD X->Y is elementary FD if there exist no partial dependency. We call this FD as Elementary FD.
- **Elementary key :** A key K is elementary key if K->Y is elementary FD.
- **Elementary prime attribute :** An attribute of elementary key is called is called elementary prime attribute.

Comment: Good try. I hope you meant "Elementary prime attribute" instead of "prime attribute" at the end. Why an attribute of elementary key should always be called "Elementary prime attribute", and not "Elementary alternate attribute" or "Elementary secondary attribute" based on different needs?

Comment: Also there is no mention of word "Prime" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_Key_Normal_Form